# How to position text accurately using Flutter layout widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, stack

I'm trying to overlay text at a specific X/Y coordinate within a Flutter layout. Here's what I want to achieve:

[image: desired result]

Currently, my layout looks like this:

[image: current result]

I want the text positioned at X: 39 and Y: 82.

I've tried using `Positioned`, but I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly. I understand `Stack` might also be a solution. Could someone please explain how to position the text accurately using Flutter's layout widgets?

**Code:**

```
class LogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LogIn> createState() => _LogInState();
}

class _LogInState extends State<LogIn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffF24004),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
              width: 350,
              height: 350,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("lib/img/pomodoro.png"),
              ))),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use a Positioned Widget inside of a Stack.

The Position Widget allows you to place at an X and Y

while the Stack ensures that the position widget is not bound by any other widgets.

Wrap your Container with those two widget like this:

```
Stack(
  children[
    Positioned(
      left: 39,
      top: 82
      child: Container(
              width: 350,
              height: 350,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("lib/img/pomodoro.png"),
          ))),
         )
       ]
)
```